# Is there any way to separate MySQL query results by table name in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Example:

```
SELECT chapter.id, book.title, book.author FROM chapter 
INNER JOIN book ON (chapter.book = book.id)
```

After fetching that query, I would like to get something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [chapter] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                )

            [book] => Array
                (
                    [title] => Lorem Ipsum
                    [author] => John Doe
                )

         )

)
```

Better yet, **stdClass** objects.

Well, after searching and working  for some time, I've found a way of doing what I want by parsing the SQL statement with [php-sql-parser](https://code.google.com/p/php-sql-parser/), But this is really not a good solution for my issue.

I have specific reasons for this, and a solution would be a great benefit for my project. Though I don't really think that there is a simpler way of doing this...

Comment: In your loop where you traverse all the rows of result set, you could easily create that new array in the desired pattern

Comment: Most database client libraries offer the metadata, e.g. to which table a result column belongs to: http://www.php.net/mysqli-result.fetch-field-direct.php http://www.php.net/mysqli-result.fetch-fields.php http://www.php.net/pdostatement.getcolumnmeta.php

Comment: Thanks @M8R-1jmw5r, I think that `mysqli_fetch_field_direct` may be the solution... I'll give it a try

Comment: @HankyPankyㇱ, All the work will be done automatically for all the queries.

Comment: Actually, I will give a try to `PDOStatement::getColumnMeta`

Comment: Thanks @M8R-1jmw5r, collecting metadata is what solved my problem!
It it exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @DMF: Great to hear it worked for you. Why don't you compile an answer your own and give a short code-example how you solved it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query         = $myPdoInstance->prepare('SELECT lorem FROM ipsum...');
$metaData      = array();
$data          = new stdClass;
$i             = 0;
$tablesIdField = 'id';

$query->execute();

while ($columnsMeta = $query->getColumnMeta($i++)) {
    $metaData[] = $columnsMeta;
}

foreach ($query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM) as $key => $columnValue) {

    $currentTable = $meta[$key]['table'];

    if (!isset($data->{$currentTable})) {
        $data->{$currentTable} = new stdClass;
    } elseif (!is_object($data->{$currentTable})) {
        $prev                                    = $data->{$currentTable};
        $data->{$currentTable}                   = new stdClass;
        $data->{$currentTable}->{$tablesIdField} = $prev;
    }

    $data->{$currentTable}->{$meta[$key]['name']} = $columnValue;
}
```

This is a **very simple example** of what I did. It is quite a solution for my project.
The code I'm using in my project is too complex and class implemented for me to post it here.

So, if there is any syntax error in this example, I'm sorry!

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to name (alias) the columns of your result set in such a way that your PHP code knows where to "file" them, e.g. with the table and column split with `:`:

```
SELECT chapter.id as `chapter:id`, book.title as `book:title`, book.author as `book:author` ...
```

Then when retrieving the results from PDO/mysqli, you can split the resulting keys to know where to store your data:

```
$formatted_row = array();
foreach ( $db_row as $column_alias => $value )
{
     list($table, $column) = explode(':', $column_alias);
     $formatted_row[$table][$column] = $value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is not as practical as i want it to be.
I'm using `PDOStatement::getColumnMeta` and collecting all meta, then building the object. It works perfectly and faster than I thought!

Comment: @DMF One advantage of this over column metadata is that you can select things other than raw columns (e.g. `count(*)`, or dates formatted in a particular way). Whether that's a big consideration or not is up to you.

Comment: +1: Good idea anyway, that would have been the alternative I would have suggested as well. I did thought about using `_` as separator. For the explode you can add the second parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The `fetch_fields()` function will give you the information you need. The script

```
<?php
$sql = "
SELECT u.user, h.db, RAND() x FROM mysql.user u
LEFT JOIN mysql.host h ON h.host = u.host
";
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'mysql');
$stmt = $conn->query($sql);
$fields = $stmt->fetch_fields();
print_r($fields);
```

produces the following output:

```
Array(
    [0] => stdClass Object(
            [name] => user
            [orgname] => User
            [table] => u
            [orgtable] => user
            [def] => 
            [db] => mysql
            ...
        )
    [1] => stdClass Object(
            [name] => db
            [orgname] => Db
            [table] => h
            [orgtable] => host
            [def] => 
            [db] => mysql
            ...
        )
    [2] => stdClass Object(
            [name] => x
            [orgname] => 
            [table] => 
            [orgtable] => 
            [def] => 
            [db] => 
            ...
        )
)
```

so you can use the `db` and `orgtable` fields to determine what table each field came from.

Comment: Yes... I have just discovered that PDO's `getColumnMeta` doesn't give you this `orgtable` (="original table") and `orgname` (="original column name") info which, depending on your requirements, can be very very useful indeed.